Entity Framework 6.4: Third-level table linking is not tracked correctly in context when used with a binding source
I have three tables. The first table is called Order, the second OrderPosition and the third Item. OrderPosition is linked to Order and Item to OderPosition. Order contains many OrderPosition and OrderPosition contains many Item.
I use Entity Framework 6.4.
If I want all the related items in table Item for a specific entry in table OrderPosition, this code works:
Dim OrderPosition = Await Task.Run(Function() _context.OrderPosition _
                               .Include(Function(a) a.Item) _
                               .FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.IdOrderPosition = OrderPosition_ID))

Dim item As New BindingList(Of DataModel.Item)(OrderPosition.Item)
BindingSourceItems.DataSource = item 

I can change/delete/add entries to table item.
However, if I now want to have all the elements of table Item that are assigned to the end of table Order, then they will be displayed, but if I make changes (e.g. the BindingSource is bound to a datagrid), then the context does not notice this and therefore cannot be saved.
I tried this code:
Dim item = Await Task.Run(Function() _context.OrderPosition _
                               .Include(Function(a) a.Item) _
                               .Where(Function(a) a.FkIdOrder = Order_ID) _
                               .SelectMany(Function(a) a.Item) _
                               .ToList())

BindingSourceItems.DataSource = New BindingList(Of DataModel.Item)(item)

Now the question is whether this is even possible and if so, how would it work?

Side note: why Await Task.Run? You may as well remove it or use async LINQ methods like ToListAsync. That said, AFAIK you should bind _context.Item.Local.ToBindingList() to the grid.

Another side note: do yourself a favor and use plural names for collection properties in classes and DbSet properties in the context.

@GertArnold Thanks for your comment! The code is part of a async sub, that's why the await task.run. If I bind _context.Item.Local.ToBindingList() directly to my grid where do I make the where clause? I can't use ToBindingList if I try to do that with Local.

Then you should await the async LINQ methods. As for the binding: you should load the data first (Await _context. ... .LoadAsync() instead of ToListAsync()) and then bind the local collection. Again, if memory serves, I remember having read this in other Stack Overflow questions.

@GertArnold Great That's working fine! Thank you very much!!

OK, great! I turned it into an answer, for good measure.

The second query (with SelectMany) seems more to the point because it queries Items directly. BTW, you can remove the Include, it is ignored.
As for the binding, I remember that DbSet.Local should be used for binding lists. First, the data should be loaded into the context:
Await _context.OrderPosition _
    .Where(Function(a) a.FkIdOrder = Order_ID) _
    .SelectMany(Function(a) a.Item) _
    .LoadAsync()

Then bind the Local collection:
BindingSourceItems.DataSource = _context.Items.Local.ToBindingList()


There is one weird thing I noted... There is a scenario where I add a new Order within the same context and after saving this Order (the function is executed again) there shouldn't any Position neither any Items in it, but it's loading Items from other Orders. Maybe the actually loaded context does have these items "cached"? Do I have to "clean" the local cache or something? Do you have an idea?
P.S. I use this within a dialog form which is called from a main form. I hand over the OrderID (in reality it is an guid) and context to the dialog form from this main form.

It's probably better to ask a new question in which you can give all necessary details. But, yes, if the context has a long lifespan it will cache everything it ever tracked. Maybe renew the context?

I will try something out and if necessary ask a new question. The weird thing is, that I never loaded these items and it is a bit illogical to use a where clause before and it's returning items from completely different entities.
